# I need to get information from a form, assign it to a property in class, and then use it in a method in another class. How?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods, properties

I have two classes, ShoppingBasket and OrderItem, and then the Form1 class. I have four properties in OrderItem that I want to use in ShoppingBasket, how do I do this?

I have textBox1 for ProductName, numericUpDown1 for Quantity and textBox2 for LatestPrice. Once the Add button is pressed I am going to add these into the listBox1. To do this I need to somehow use the properties that are in the class OrderItem; ProductName, Quantity, LatestPrice and TotalOrder(which would be Quantity x LatestPrice). Then I need to use these properties in the method AddProduct which is in the class ShoppingBasket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    ShoppingBasket addButtonShoppingBasket = new ShoppingBasket();

    addButtonShoppingBasket.AddProduct(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));
}
}
```

Shopping Basket:

```
public class ShoppingBasket
{
public ShoppingBasket()
{

}

public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestProductValue, int quantity)
{

}
}
```

OrderItem:

```
public class OrderItem
{

public OrderItem(string productName, decimal latestPrice, int quantity)
{
    ProductName = productName;
    LatestPrice = latestPrice;
    Quantity = quantity;
    TotalOrder = latestPrice * quantity;
}

public string ProductName { get; set; }

public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public decimal TotalOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you should add container for your `OrderItem` in `ShoppingBasket`. Like `Lis<OrderItem> products`, and then

```
public void AddProduct(string productName, 
                       decimal latestProductValue, 
                       int quantity)
{   
    products.Add(new OrderItem(productName, latestProductValue, quantity));
}
```

to access `OrderItem`'s properties  your just write `OrderItem.Quantity = 3`

and better create `Add` method wich will just accept `OrderItem`:

```
public void AddProduct(OrderItem sb)
{

}
```

and something about your `OrderItem`, `TotalOrder` property should be readonly(have only `get` method):

```
public decimal TotalOrder { get; }
```